# Windows 10: Can I reverse the order of jumplist menu items in task bar context (right click) menu (after moving task bar to right and not bottom)

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, jumplist

The user moved task bar from traditional bottom position to the right. That is because the user wants it this way and prefers it on the side.

But, after such change - the ability to "close all windows" is now a long mouse travel distance (in the jumplist). In other words, it is optimized for bottom task bar position.

How can I tweak windows registry or deep settings to make 'close window' appear on the top of the menu.

See pic below of ordering that the user wants to reverse

[image]

Comment: Jumplist order is configured in the registry, however, whether or not this specific entry in the jumplist can be moved is uncertain since it's an OS default entry. If it is possible, you only have three position options to choose from, as there is a hierarchy: `bottom`, `middle`, or `top`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest returning to the default way of doing things.

Right click on the Task Bar and select Unlock.

Then firmly drag the Task Bar to the bottom where it normally lives.

That is the best way (in my opinion) as some of the task bar buttons do not move (even unlocked). The overall operation of the task bar does not change either.

I just tried this on my machine here.

N.B.  Just to be clear, you can move some icons back and forth, but you cannot move the Start Button and thus cannot reverse the order, or the order of things attached to the task bar.

Comment: To be clear, the entries when you right-click a taskbar icon which appear, are called jump lists. Start button and other taskbar icons are actually not related here, the OP wants to move only the jump list entries, specifically the "Close window" to top which is not AFAIK possible. I also don't know if the OP wants to optimise the taskbar, so the jump lists and icons reverse, and get "optimised" for the new position, which is also not possible, but I don't think that the OP wants to unlock and move the taskbar to bottom again.

Comment: The desired behavior cannot be accomplished with the Task Bar on the right side. We have to use it as given when placed that way. That is why I suggest the bottom layout to make things work better.

Comment: correct, OP now edited the question to show that the desire is to keep bar on the side. Not go  back to bottom position.

Comment: at wasif - yeah - I was suspecting there is no "deep tweak" to achieve that. So - new feature request to microsoft then....

Answer (score 0):

Right click then press uparrow when the menu pops up.  It will take you straight to close window.